# d3 v4 simulation jumping around every change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like help getting an Graph example to work in D3 version 4. I've scoured the documentation and other questions, yet I can't get it to work. Help is very much appreciated.

I'm working on getting the graph from an example to version 4. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795
The problem is that any updates to the graph make the nodes reset to a new position. What I've got so far is:

```
...
//redraw code
let node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes);
node.enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
node.exit().remove();

simulation
  .nodes(nodes)
...
```

http://codepen.io/rrmoelker/pen/QKQxaR

My feeling is that I'm breaking the pairing between the simulation item and the DOM element. But however I try, I can't get them to stay together.

[image: d3 v4 online graph editing issue]